# How to verify multiple XCTestExpectations using a predicate checking the hittable attribute in XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

Using `XCTest's XCTWaiter` class, I would like to check on a `predicate`, namely:
`NSPredicate(format: "hittable == true")` in an **XCTNSPredicateExpectation** expectation in
open

```
class func wait(for expectations: [XCTestExpectation], timeout seconds: TimeInterval, enforceOrder enforceOrderOfFulfillment: Bool) -> XCTWaiterResult`
```

I would like to verify this predicate in multiple XCTestExpectation expectations. I think this is the most time efficient way to check that multiple elements on a particular screen are hittable.

I discovered that the combination of using the hittable predicate on an array with more than one expectations results in the error

```
`Assertion Failure: <unknown>:0: Neither attributes nor error returned`
```

If I use the exists predicate, the verification of an array of expectations in `wait(for:timeout:enforceOrder:)` works well. Also, if the array of expectations contains just one expectation, the verification works fine in combination with the hittable `predicate`.

Here is a test method that shows the issue if you run it in an **XCTestCase** subclass, you need to adjust the identifiers to something on your app that is hittable at the same time on a screen:

```
func testAssertThatMultipleElementsAreHittable() {
    let accessibilityIdentifiers = ["lapTimer", "eventTimer", "startButton", "stopButton"]
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "hittable == true") //fails with hittable, but passes with exists!
    var expectations = [XCTNSPredicateExpectation]()

    accessibilityIdentifiers.forEach { (identifier) in
        expectations.append(XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: predicate, object: XCUIApplication().descendants(matching: .any)[identifier]))
    }

    let result = XCTWaiter.wait(for: expectations, timeout: 5.0, enforceOrder: false)
    if result != .completed { 
        XCTFail("waiting failed!")
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea what is going on here?